# How prove this isn't exist prime number $p>7$

Tags: number-theory

show that: there isn't exsit prime number $p>7$,such
$p^{12}+5039\times 5041$  the factor number  is less than $120$

I think maybe use Fermat theorem? How can solve it? Thank you

Comment: Yes,That's you mean,Thank you

Comment: Actually, do you consider only prime factors?

Comment: No,is not only prime factors,Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you saying there is no prime $p\gt7$ such that that expression has a factor less than 120? or that there is no prime $p\gt7$ such that that expression *doesn't* have a factor less than 120? If $p\ge3$ is prime then the number is even, so it has 2 as a factor. The question is very unclear to me.

Comment: What is meant by the "factor number"?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter,for exaplem the number $12$ factor number is $1,2,3,4,6,12$,

Comment: @GerryMyerson,Hello,I think mean is there is no prime $p>7$ such that that expression doesn't have a factor less than $120$

Comment: @math110, but that's trivial, as for each prime exceeding 2 the expression has the factor 2. I think what's meant is that for every prime greater than 7 the expression has 120 as a factor, but that's sure not what it says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint* : $5040=7!$ , $120=5!$ , and $p=2k+1$. Our expression becomes: $$p^{12}+5039\cdot5041=p^{12}+(7!-1)(7!+1)=p^{12}+(7!^2-1)=(p^{12}-1)+7!^2=\\=(p^6-1)(p^6+1)+7!^2=(p^3-1)(p^3+1)\cdot(p^2+1)(p^4-p^2+1)+7!^2=\\=(p-1)(p^2+p+1)\cdot(p+1)(p^2-p+1)\cdot(p^2+1)(p^4-p^2+1)+5!^2\cdot42^2$$ $p>7>2\iff p=2k+1\iff(p-1),(p+1)$, and $p^2+1$ are all multiples of $2\iff$ the product is a multiple of $2^3=8$. Also, since $p>7>3\iff p=3k\pm1\iff p\mp1$ is a multiple of $3\iff$ the product is also a multiple of $3$. $p>7>5\iff p=5k\pm1$ or $p=5k\pm2$. In the former case, $p\mp1$ is a multiple of $5$, in the latter, $p^2+1$ is divisible through $5\iff$ the product is a multiple of $5$ as well, meaning that the entire sum divides through $5!=120$ , for all primes $p>7$

---

If however the total number of factors is what's actually meant, then let us first notice that the expression divides through $2$ *once more*, because $(p-1)(p+1)=2k(2k+2)=4k(k+1)$, and $k(k+1)$ is always even, generating an *extra* factor of $2$ ; through $3$ *twice*, because of $p^2\pm p+1$ ; as well as through $7$. $[\ p=7k\pm1\iff7|p\mp1$ ; $p=7k\pm2\iff7|p^2\pm p+1$ ; $p=7k\pm3$ $\iff7|p^2\mp p+1\ ]$. Thus, $N=2^4\cdot3^2\cdot5^1\cdot7^1\cdot n^1$ , implying a minimum of $(4+1)\cdot(2+1)\cdot$ $(1+1)\cdot(1+1)\cdot(1+1)=120$ factors. — *Thanks to user [Achille Hui](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59379/achille-hui) for his invaluable help !*

Comment: then? Thank you, can you post your full solution?

Comment: what was the question supposed to say?

Comment: Hello,why  isn't exsit $p$ ?can you explain?,Thank you

Comment: $5040 = 2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 | p^{12} - 1$ for prime $p > 7$.

Comment: Yes, because $(p-1)(p+1)=2k(2k+2)=4k(k+1)$ , and $k(k+1)$ spits out yet another factor of $2$, thus increasing the total number of divisors to $60$. But how do we double it to $120$ ?

Comment: Notice $p^{12} + 5039 \cdot 5041 = 2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot X$ for some $X > 5040$.
It has following $120$ factors $2^a 3^b 5^c 7^d X^e$ where $0 \le a \le 4, 0 \le b \le 2, 0 \le c, d, e \le 1$. Since $X > 5040$, all these factors are distinct.

Comment: Something tells me I should be feeling pretty [silly](http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/184/c/6/triple_facepalm_by_spottedheart98464-d3kuyp3.png) right now... :-)